# how to set divider padding for IconPageIndicator in viewpagerindicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am using `IconPageIndicator` from libary `viewPagerIndicator` now i need to set a margin between each icons. Is it possible to set a padding between icons `IconPageIndicator` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)** instead of viewPagerIndicator lib, It is part of **android  support package v4**, and you can use

```
void    setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

for setting desired padding

Comment: i need to show just icons so i am using IconPageIndicator.
Does pageTabStrip support icon indicator?

Comment: yes, just don't return any title in getPageTitle in your PagerAdapter

Comment: no. i implement it using IconPageIndicator itself.i gave some transparent padding to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to declare divider padding for ViewPagerIndicator in activity theme.
Please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22763404/1866122